# Mi array tiene datos, pero cuando intento acceder a ellos aparece como si no existieran

Tags: javascript, array

Tengo el siguiente código:

```js
let pokeData = [];

fetch("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=50")
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then(function(allpokemon) {
    allpokemon.results.forEach(function(pokemon) {
      pokeData.push(pokemon);
    });
  });

console.log(pokeData.length);
console.log(pokeData);
```

Mi problema es que cuando intento acceder con `console.log(pokeData[0].name);` me devuelve `undefined` en la consola.

Si coloco `console.log(pokeData.length);` y cuando llamo `console.log(pokeData)` me aparece los 50 objetos que inserté.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tienes que entender el funcionamiento del [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Utilizando_Fetch). Te explico la secuencia de lo que está pasando.

1. Declaras tu variable `pokeData`
2. Haces la llamada **asíncrona** `fetch` a un endpoint externo. Es importante que entiendas qué es una llamada asíncrona y qué es una [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise).
3. Inmediatamente después haces el `console.log`. En este punto la llamada no ha terminado y por tanto no tienes datos (de ahí tu `undefined`).
4. Cuando examinas la variable en las `devtools`, la llamada ya ha terminado y ha hecho la asignación del `then`, por eso ves datos.

En este ejemplo podrás ver que el orden de los `console.logs` en el código es distinto al orden en el que se ejecutan realmente.

```js
let pokeData = [];

fetch("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=50")
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then(function (allpokemon) {
    allpokemon.results.forEach(function (pokemon) {
      pokeData.push(pokemon);
    });
    console.log(`Aquí ya tengo todos mis pokemons (${pokeData.length}) y el primero es ${pokeData[0].name}`)
  });

console.log('Aquí no tengo mis datos asignados todavía porque la promise del fetch no ha terminado');
console.log(pokeData.length);
console.log(pokeData);

setTimeout(()=>{
console.log('Esto no hay que hacerlo nunca pero así ves que si esperas un poco los datos ya están');
  console.log(pokeData.length);
  console.log(pokeData[0].name);
},2000)
```

Te recomiendo

Answer (score 2):

La razón por la que `console.log(pokeData[0].name);` devuelve `undefined` es porque se ejecuta antes de que la función`fetch` obtenga algún tipo de información del servidor:

```js
fetch("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=50")
  ...
```

Por lo tanto, el resultado fue que intentó acceder a los datos aún no almacenados en el *array* `pokeData`.

#### Solución

Una posible solución sería la que sigue:

```js
const pokeData = [];

// Creamos nuestra función con dos parámetros: ruta, fn
const obtenerDatos = (ruta, fn) => {
  fetch(ruta)
    .then((respuesta) => respuesta.json())
    .then((allpokemon) => {
      allpokemon.results.forEach((pokemon) => {
        pokeData.push(pokemon);
      });

      // Nuestra función que hemos pasado como parámetro:
      fn();
    });
};

obtenerDatos("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=50", function() {
  console.log(pokeData[0].name);
});
```

Cuando ejecutamos la función `obtenerDatos( ruta, fn )` obtenemos los datos del servidor (`ruta`) y luego ejecutará la función (`fn`) una vez haya terminado de obtenerlo:

Por ejemplo:

```js
obtenerDatos(ruta, function () {
  // Se ejecuta después de obtener los datos
  // del servidor.
});
```

> Tome en cuenta que la función `fetch()` devuelve una promesa. Si desea ampliar un poco sobre este tema puede consultar [Uso de Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Utilizando_Fetch) y [Usar promesas](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Usar_promesas) del sitio Web Oficial de Mozilla.

Answer (score 1):

LO que puedes hacer es usar **await** cuando uses **fetch**, así espera a que termine de traerte todos los datos y luego continua con la siguiente línea de código, esto a mi me soluciona muchas cosas, hay que poner la palabra reservada **async** en la función donde estés usando un **await**

```
let UrlPokeAPI = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/";

async function loadPokemon(url) {
   try {

      let res = await fetch(url),
         pokemones= await res.json(),

//aquí pones todo el código que deseas ejecutar
      console.log(pokemones);


   } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
   }
}

d.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (e) => {
   loadPokemon(UrlPokeAPI);
});
```